# How can I use the tmpfs to accelerate my chrome browser start up?

Tags: debian, chrome, tmpfs

Every time when I am trying to start the chrome browser, it is a little bit slow because the chrome need to load the cache and that may cause a big amount of disk IO.

My distribution is Debian Wheezy(7.0),and what should I do to make the browser start faster? Use the `tmpfs` and how?

Answer (score 2):

tmpfs is not better than the disk cache. So if you want to speed up the Chrome start then you just need to read all the files which Chrome is going to need:

```
cat file1 file2 file2 ... >/dev/null
```

If you find out in which order the files are on the disk then you can optimize the access by reading them in the right order.

If you start Chrome afterwards then all its read accesses will be served from the VFS cache.